# Django - Return all objects in table where attribute A is in list B OR attribute C is in list D

Tags: python, django, django-views

So below I have this code where the request has the current `User` object. A `User` can have "followers" which are represented by `FollowUser` and they can follow another user's goal, which is represented by `FollowGoal`. I want to return all the posts that the current user which is represented by `request.user`. I want to be able to get all posts where the `creator` is someone the current user is following or is a goal the current user is following. As you can see below I generate a list of `UUID` for both the `followees` of the current user (people they are following) as well as a list of `UUID` for the goals the current user is following. Then I do `<attribute>__in`, but for some reason it's returning an empty list. Even if I just filter by followees or follow goals. Not sure why it's returning an empty list. I generated fake data that represent both the cases of posts created by followees of the current user and goals the current user is following. The `Post` object should filter if the creator is by someone the current user is following OR the goal is a goal the currrent user is following.

view.py

```
def get_current_user_followee(request):
    current_user = request.user
    followee_list = list(FollowUser.objects.filter(follower=current_user).values_list('followee', flat=True))
    followee_list.append(current_user.uuid)
    return [str(followee) for followee in followee_list]


def get_current_user_join_goal_follow(request):
    current_user = request.user
    join_goal_list = list(FollowGoal.objects.filter(follower=current_user).values_list('uuid', flat=True))
    return [str(join_goal_follow) for join_goal_follow in join_goal_list]

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_initial_posts(request, count):
    join_goal_list = get_current_user_join_goal_follow(request)
    followee_list = get_current_user_followee(request)
    serializer = full_post_data_serializer(
        Post.objects.filter(join_goal__in=join_goal_list, creator__in=followee_list).order_by('-uuid')[:count])
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ulid does ordered uuid creation
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=generate_ulid_as_uuid, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator")
    join_goal = models.ForeignKey(JoinGoal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=511, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)])
    hash_tags = models.ManyToManyField(HashTag)
    type = models.CharField(
        choices=PostType.choices,
        max_length=2,
    )

class FollowGoal(AbstractSimpleModel):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='goal_follow')
    join_goal = models.ForeignKey(JoinGoal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # No update added, because cannot be edited. Can only be added and deleted

class FollowUser(AbstractSimpleModel):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follower_id')
    followee = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='followee_id')
    # No update added, because cannot be edited. Can only be added and deleted

class User(AbstractDatesModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(8)])
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.objects.filter(join_goal__in=join_goal_list, creator__in=followee_list)
```

is kind of close, but it means BOTH join_goal in my_list AND creator in followees

to join with OR you need to use Q expressions

```
from django.db.models import Q
join_goal_query = Q(join_goal__in = join_goal_list)
follower_post_query = Q(creator__in = followee_list)
is_join_goal_OR_follower_post = join_goal_query | follower_post_query
Post.objects.filter(is_join_goal_OR_follower_post ).all()
```

Comment: does `join_goal_list` and `followee_list` need to be list of `UUID`s or `str`?